# How can I use concatenation in where clause [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello I'm trying to use concatenation in where clause in codeigniter 
Equivelent to this in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `tblstaff` WHERE concat_ws(' ',firsname,lastname) like '%Firstname lastname%'
```

I tried doing this in codeigniter , but didn't work

```
$admin = 'Firstname lastname';

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->where('firstname'.' '.'lastname',$admin);

return $CI->db->get('tblstaff')->row()->default_language;
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but try to change

```
$CI->db->where('firstname'.' '.'lastname',$admin);
```

to

```
 $CI->db->where("CONCAT_WS(' ',firsname,lastname) LIKE '%".$admin."%'", NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try codeigniter's query builder `$this->db->like` As below:

```
$admin = 'Firstname lastname';

$CI->db->like("CONCAT_WS(' ',firsname,lastname)",$admin,"both");
```

For more see here...https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data